# How to Visualize ROC curve using predict_generator and generate_arrays_for_predict?

Tags: python, keras, generator, predict, roc

I want to plot ROC curve using `predict_generator` . I don't know if that possible while using my code.I didn't find any code to help me how to plot ROC curve while using `generate_arrays_for_predict`.
I found this code to plot ROC curve

`y_pred_keras = keras_model.predict(X_test).ravel()`

`fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(y_pred, preictPrediction)` I have edited it to fit with my code but I got this error because I use `generate_arrays_for_predict` error:`Expected array-like(array or non-string sequence),got<generator object generate_arrays_for_predict>`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
def generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x=np.array([x])
            x=x.swapaxes(0,1)
            yield(x)
preictPrediction=model.predict_generator(generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath), max_queue_size=4, steps=len(filesPath))
y_pred=generate_arrays_for_predict(indexPat, filesPath)
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(y_pred, preictPrediction)
```

Comment: The details you provided aren't relevant, nor can we know what the latter two methods are ("I found this code", what code?). I happen to have this implemented, so if you rephrase it as "How to visualize ROC given preds and labels" (1D array or list for each), I can help.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I have the same problem.I am very interested to know how to plot ROC curve while using `generate_arrays_for_predict`

Comment: Show clearly what are the labels and predictions; each must be a 1D array or list. I can see latter is `y_pred_keras`, but labels appears to be a generator; you can't visualize with a generator expression - it can be a batch, or several. Consume the generator (iterate until exhaustion), and assign to `y_true`, then include what the resulting shape is (`np.array(y_true).shape`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon predictions is `preictprediction` and labels as you say is the generator, so now I will add `y_true = list(generate_arrays_for_predict)` to my code and `np.array(y_true).shape` to see the resulting shape.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I got memoryerror `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 32.3 MiB for an array with shape (1, 10, 22, 5, 3844) and data type float64`.Do you know how to solve this error ??

Comment: That is a separate question. For the sake of the current question, you can just "pretend" you have the labels and predictions and figure the rest later; so formulate it as if you seek to visualize ROC given preds & labels.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I can't solve this memoryerror because I have data with large size. Is there another method to visualize ROC curve without converting generators to a list ??

Comment: It isn't the labels that don't fit in memory, but the data; you need to decouple them (load separately). Can get predictions via generator, then load labels separately (but ensure in same order). (That, too, is a question of its own.)